# Cannot read property 'get' of undefined when uploading image in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

**Cannot read property 'get' of undefined**
When uploading in the editor

When uploading at media library, the upload is very slow and eventually cannot get this:

***"The webpage might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address."***

Theme name      i   Newsmag
**PHP Version       i   7.3.11-1+ubuntu
18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1**
max_execution_time          300
max_input_vars          5000
WP Memory Limit         256 MB/request
WP version      i   5.4